# How to decide if a parameter is the click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which can be called by either a click event or directly. When I call it directly, I need pass it a data parameter, so I've defined the function to accept a parameter to account for the direct call with the parameter.

```
function myFunc(param){

}
```

Within the function, I need to differentiate whether the function was called directly or from the click event, so what I thought I could simply check if param is set. If it's set, then the function is called directly. If it's not set, then it's called from the click event.

The problem is that a click event by default passes an event object. So even when the function is called by the click event, param won't be null.

So is there a way to check whether the param passed is the click event?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Can't you define a separate function that is passed into the click events?

Comment: No, this code can be triggered when the user clicks, or directly from the code itself. Why would I repeat the code twice in 2 different functions?

Comment: Ideally your function wouldn't care how it was called.  It would do the work it knows how to do, and just that...  

Worst case, look at window.event properties to find the event type that was called, or add a second parameter (byEvent = true/false), and check that.

Comment: Why does your function need to how it's being called?

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen, the function needs to get the parameters or set default parameters if no data is passed. So I check if `data==null` but during click (when I don't pass parameters), data is still not null (because it gets passed the click event by default). This is why I need to know where this data came from exactly (data I passed or the event data).

Comment: You should modify the call environment so you make sure it gets called with the same data, no matter if it's from a click event or manual call.

Comment: @JMC `byEvent` is a good way, but @Vinyl Windows suggested I check the `.clientX` property which gets passed by click events.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to duplicate any code. The proper way to do this is to handle the click event with an event handler, and the action you want to take in another function. For example:

```
// define main action
var doSomethingUseful = function(is_clicked) {
  // write some code here
}

// define click handler
var myBtnClicked = function(e) {
  doSomethingUseful(true);
}

// bind click event
$('#my_button').click(myBtnClicked);
```

Although, as was already mentioned to you, the fact that you need to know that information is *usually* a warning sign that there might be a simpler way to do things.

**edit** for example:

```
// define main action
var doSomethingUseful = function() {
  // write some code here that doesn't care "why" it's being called
}

// define click handler
var myBtnClicked = function(e) {
  // do the click-only stuff

  // call the generic function
  doSomethingUseful();
}

// bind click event
$('#my_button').click(myBtnClicked);
```

Comment: he is asking to use only one function. if the above is the case there is no reason to ask his question.

Comment: He is asking to use one function for the wrong reason. In his own words: "Why would I repeat the code twice in 2 different functions"

Answer (score 1):

IE's before version 9 don't always pass the event argument, so the parameter will be be undefined if it is called from an IE click.

```
function myFunc(param){
if(!param) || param.clientX)// not called with a data param
}
```

You would do better to check for the data than for the event.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the .clientX property that is passed to the click event.

```
  function(param){

   if(param.clientX){//this is a click event}
    else
    {//this is a call event};

};
```

You may want to use this one.

```
   function(param){

       if(param.target){//this is a click event}
        else
        {//this is a call event};

    };
```

Comment: I upvoted this, but it seems someone else downvoted it, I hope they would explain why. But I have a question: are you sure that a click event always has a clientX property all the time in all browsers?

Comment: You may want to use param.target in the place of clientX; however, i just tested Chrome, FF, and IE9 and clientX works in these.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#someID').click(function(){ 
        myFunc(true);
    });
    myFunc();
});

function myFunc(param){
    param ? alert("click"):alert("not click");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunc(param) {

    // which (aka keyCode) is a property set to params
    // by jQuery for any event


    // Check for object make you free to pass parameter 
    // as object also with string, array and so on

    if (Object.prototype.toString(param) == '[object Object]' && param.which) {
        // called by clck
        console.log(param.which);
    } else {
        // called by function
        console.log(param);
    }
}

$('#clickable').click(myFunc)

// passing parameter as object
myFunc({
    a: 'abc',
    b: 'def'
});​

// passing parameter as string
myFunc('Hello');

// passing parameter as array
myFunc([1, 2, 2]);
```

and so on.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NKhKn/3/)**